# Continuity of function of several variables?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

Let $U ,V\subset R^n$ be **closed**  subset of $R^n$, $f(x,y)$ is defined on $U\times V$.If for any $x_0\in U$, $f(x_0,y)$ is continue about $y\in V$, and for any $y_0\in V$, $f(x,y_0)$ is continue about $x\in U$.

Then ,can I get that $f(x,y)$ is continue on $U\times V$ ?

If I can't get that, what condition should be added to make $f(x,y)$ is continue?

If the **closed** be changed to open or measurable ,what will happen?

Thanks for any hint or detail answer.

Comment: Let $U = [-1,1] = V$, $f(x,y) = u(x)u(y)$ where $u$ is the Heaviside step (pick any convention). Then around the point $x_0 = -0.5$, $f$ is continuous for all $y$, and vice versa, but the function itself is not continuous on $[-1,1] \times [-1,1]$.

Comment: @stochasticboy321  $u(x_0)u(y)$ should be continuous for all $y\in[-1,1]$ and vice versa.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 I mean for any $x_0\in [-1,1]$ also. So for $x_0>0$ this is not the case.

Comment: Generally, a separately continuous function is not continuous. I'm not sure whether there is any reasonable condition that ensures continuity without directly requiring continuity.

Comment: @DanielFischer May I have an example?

Comment: $$f(x,y) = \begin{cases} 0 &, x = 0 \text{ or } y = 0 \\ \frac{x}{y} &, 0 < \lvert x\rvert \leqslant \lvert y\rvert \\ \frac{y}{x} &, \lvert y\rvert < \lvert x\rvert\end{cases}$$ is separately continuous, but not continuous at $(0,0)$ (since $f(\xi,\xi) = 1$ for all $\xi \neq 0$).

Comment: @DanielFischer   good example

Comment: Theorem (Luzin, 1948): For a function of two real variables $f(x,y)$ on a rectangle $R=[a,b]\times[c,d]$, $f$ is continuous on $R$ iff $f(x,\phi(x))$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ for all continuous functions $\phi\colon[a,b]\to[c,d]$.

Comment: @A.G. So thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Daniel Fischer added in the comments, if one of the families of sections $(1)\,\,\,\{x\to f(x,y),y\in V\}$ or $(2)\,\,\,\{y\to f(x,y), x\in U\}$ is equicontinuous then $f(x,y)$ is continuous:

If $(1)$, then
$$|f(x,y)-f(x_0,y_0)|\leq |f(x,y)-f(x_0,y)|+|f(x_0,y)-f(x_0,y_0)|\leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon$$
for $\|(x,y)-(x_0,y_0)\|_{\mathbb R^{n\times n}}$ small enough.

If $(2)$, then
$$|f(x,y)-f(x_0,y_0)|\leq |f(x,y)-f(x,y_0)|+|f(x,y_0)-f(x_0,y_0)|\leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon$$
for $\|(x,y)-(x_0,y_0)\|_{\mathbb R^{n\times n}}$ small enough.

Comment: The $\delta(y)$ to get $\lvert f(x,y) - f(x_0,y)\rvert \leqslant \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ depends on $y$. In general, a separately continuous function is not continuous.

Comment: @DanielFischer Aha, it should be uniformly continuous in $y$ for this to work ?

Comment: If you require the family of sections $\{ x \mapsto f(x,y) : y \in V\}$ to be equicontinuous, the argument works.

Comment: Thanks ,I think equicontinuous is the weakest condition (or necessary and sufficient condition) make this to work.

Comment: I think it is only sufficient condition.